# Problema con belongsTo en Laravel, no devuelve el registro relacionado

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy implementando en Laravel una relación uno-uno, en donde un alumno puede tener una sola nota final y una nota final pertenece a un solo alumno.

La relación para obtener la nota de un alumno me funciona bien, pero la relación inversa, de saber a qué alumno pertenece una nota, me está arrojando null.

La información que puedo aportar es la siguiente:

Los modelos son:

ALUMNOS

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Alumnos extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre', 'edad', 'curso'
    ];
    
    public function nota(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Notas');
    }   
}
```

NOTAS

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Notas extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'posicion', 'nota'
    ];

    public function alumno(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Alumnos');
    }
}
```

Las migraciones de creación de las tablas son:

ALUMNOS

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateAlumnosTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('alumnos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->integer('edad');
            $table->string('curso');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('alumnos');
    }
}
```

NOTAS

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateNotasTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()    
    {
        Schema::create('notas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('alumnos_id')->unique();
            $table->foreign('alumnos_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('alumnos')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('posicion');
            $table->integer('nota');            
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('notas');
    }
}
```

En la BD tengo estos registros en estas dos tablas:

ALUMNOS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

NOTAS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando ejecuto en Tinker:

Obtengo correctamente la nota para el primer alumno

```
>>> use App\Models\Alumnos;
>>> $alumno=Alumnos::find(1);
=> App\Models\Alumnos {#4553
     id: 1,
     nombre: "Pepe",
     edad: 15,
     curso: "3A",
     created_at: "2021-02-20 04:30:40",
     updated_at: "2021-02-20 04:30:40",
   }
>>> $alumno->nota;
=> App\Models\Notas {#4557
     id: 1,
     alumnos_id: 1,
     posicion: 2,
     nota: 7,
     created_at: "2021-02-20 04:31:13",
     updated_at: "2021-02-20 04:31:13",
   }
```

Pero a la inversa, no logro obtener el alumno asociado a una nota

```
>>> use App\Models\Notas;
>>> $nota=Notas::find(1);
=> App\Models\Notas {#4553
     id: 1,
     alumnos_id: 1,
     posicion: 2,
     nota: 7,
     created_at: "2021-02-20 04:31:13",
     updated_at: "2021-02-20 04:31:13",
   }
>>> $nota->alumno;
=> null
>>>
```

Debería traer al usuario 1, Pepe.

Si alguien puede identificar dónde está el problema, le estaré muy agradecido.

Comment: El código debe ir como texto, ;)

Comment: Hola, gracias por lo que sugieres, pero a qué código te refieres? y  si debe ir como texto, es encerrándolo en comillas simples ?, por favor, puedes ser un poco más explicito, gracias.

Comment: @BetaM, tienes razón, he subido el código como print screen. Lo voy a cambiar. Me disculpo por este fallo de formalidad.

Comment: Hice el cambio, dejé la clave foranea como alumno_id, pero al ejecutar tinker: >>> use App\Models\Alumnos;
>>> $nota=Notas::find(1); me arroja error:  Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'notas.alumnos_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `notas` where `notas`.`alumnos_id` = 1 and `notas`.`alumnos_id` is not null limit 1)', esto me lleva a pensar que está esperando que el nombre de la clave foranea se llame "alumnos_id".

Comment: no @JuncoFuerte de hecho si lees la documentación es al revés, espera que el nombre sea `alumno_id` para que tinker reconozca el cambio hecho debes cerrarlo y volver a abrirlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ya te mencionaba, el error se debe a que la llave foránea en *notas* no sigue la convención de nombres [esperada por Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one), dado lo anterior entonces debes declararla de forma explícita en el método **`nota`** como segundo argumento en la relación *hasOne*

```
$this->hasOne(Modelo::class, 'alumnos_id');
```

Comentarios finales:

- Si quieres evitar estas configuraciones extra entonces en la medida de lo posible trata de seguir los lineamientos que da la propia documentación
- El error que mencionas en los comentarios es por que *tinker* necesita *ser reiniciado* para que los cambios en tu código surtan efecto, de otro modo aunque hagas modificaciones estas no se verán aplicadas sobre la consulta que estás trabajando